# C: Read() and consuming newline character

Tags: c, buffer, newline

So, when you're reading input with getchar() you need to consume the character entered as well as the newline used to submit the character.

However, I'm trying to use read() to read input into a buffer. The program may be reading from the keyboard or from an input file. When I enter a character into my program it reads in the character and the newline, but anything entered beyond the first character is not read into the buffer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        //Success/failure of read
        int read_status = 1;
        //Success/failure of write
        int write_status = 1;
        //Buffer for reads/writes
        char buffer[BUFSIZ] = {0};
        int charsRead;

        for(charsRead = 0; charsRead < BUFSIZ && read_status > 0; charsRead++)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Ready to read.\n");
            read_status = read(0, buffer, 2);

            fprintf(stderr, "First status: %i.\n", read_status);

            fprintf(stderr, "Read a : ");
            if(buffer[charsRead] == '\n')
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "newline\n");
            }
            else if(buffer[charsRead] == ' ')
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "space\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%c\n", buffer[charsRead]);
            }
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Printing read in chars: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < charsRead; i++)
        {
            if(buffer[i] == '\n')
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "newline\n");
            }
            else if(buffer[i] == ' ')
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "space\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%c\n", buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I run it, it produces this output:

```
Ready to read.
a
First status: 2.
Read a : a
Ready to read.
b
First status: 2.
Read a : newline
Ready to read.
a
First status: 2.
Read a :
Ready to read.
b
First status: 2.
Read a :
Ready to read.
g
First status: 2.
Read a :
Ready to read.
e
First status: 2.
Read a :
Ready to read.
First status: 0.
Read a :
Printing read in chars:
e
newline
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
```

Am I misunderstanding how read works? I've tried adding another read after the first in an attempt to consume the newline, but, it doesn't resolve the issue.

This program will also be writing to stdout (which is going to be pipe). Is there any special considerations I need to make for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone interested I figured the answer out. The problem is that I wasn't moving the pointer to buffer along, so I was overwriting the first index over and over again.

So, this is how I got it working:

```
for(bytesRead = 0; bytesRead < BUFSIZ && read_status > 0; bytesRead++)
{
    read_status = read(0, buffer + bytesRead, 1);
}
```